# R can not find path to rtools

Tags: r, path

I try to install rtools for R. The installation goes successful and I add rtools to the environment variables. However, when I run

```
devtools::find_rtool()
```

I get the following response

```
Error: running command '"C:/R/R-34~1.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save
--no-restore --quiet CMD config CC' had status 65535
```

I have tried to reinstall both R and rtools, but didn't solve the problem.

If I run

```
Sys.getenv('PATH')
```

I get the following output

```
    [1] "C:\\Rtools\\bin;C:\\R\\R-3.4.3\\bin\\x64;C:\\RBuildTools\\3.4\\bin;
C:\\RBuildTools\\3.4\\mingw_32\\bin;
C:\\Rtools\\bin;C:\\Rtools\\mingw_32\\bin;
  C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\130\\Tools\\Binn\\;
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\Tools\\Binn\\;
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\DTS\\Binn\\;
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\Tools\\Binn\\ManagementStudio\\;
C:\\Users\\viking.fristrom\\AppData\\Local\\GitHubDesktop\\bin;"
```

I am using

```
-R 3.4.3  
- rtools 3.4  
Runing on Windows 10.
```

Comment: I see both 32 bit and 64 bit Rtools locations in path.

Comment: you need to clean up your `PATH` - `C:\\Rtools\\bin` appears twice and probably you want the `C:\\RBuildTools\\3.4\\bin` ahead of it. Plus it looks like you want to run 64bit R while you have added `mingw_32`

Comment: I've reinstalled R and Rtools now but only the 64 bit version to avoid possible problems there. I also clean up the path variables so that there are no duplicates and they only points to the 64 bit versions. However, the problem still remains